# Laravel 5 Reflection Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When trying to load my main index I the following error. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIeEN.png)

I've spent hours trying to fix this, my files are as follow:

-routes.php

```
   <?php

   Route::get('/', [
        'uses'  => '\instyle\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index',
       'as'    => 'home',
    ]);
```

-Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace instyle\Http\Controllers;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

-HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace instyle\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

and my folders are as follows

```
 --instyle
 -- --app
 -- -- -- Http
 -- -- -- -- Controllers
 -- -- -- -- -- Controller.php
 -- -- -- -- -- HomeController.php
 -- -- -- Requests
 -- -- -- -- Kernel.php
```

Any ideas where I messed up?

Comment: what happens if you reference only `HomeController@index` ?

Comment: And by the way, have you set the app:name on the beggining of the project?

Comment: If I only reference HomeController@index I get a "FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 4: Class 'app\Http\Controllers\BaseController' not found" So it looks like BaseController wich is what the abrstract class controller inherits from doesn't exist.
Doesn't laravel5 Use a base controller?

Comment: @EChan42 what does your composer.json file look like, particularly the autoload PSR-4 section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your namespacing is wrong. The project folder should probably not be a part of it, and you forget the `app` part. Try this namespace in both of your controllers:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

And then your route would use this method call:

```
'uses'  => '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index',
```

Comment: The app part of the namespace is relative for what he had set on the `app:name` artisan command. if he set the namespace to `instyle` it would'nt be right according to the usual namespace standard.

Comment: I know that, but it's not very likely that a beginner has changed the namespace. Asking them to try the default namespace is a sound idea.

Comment: Indeed...i've asked him, lets see what he answer and we can give him better advices.

Comment: Adding the namespace and route you provided gives me:
    " ReflectionException in Route.php line 287: Class Instyle\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist "

Adding "'uses'  => '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index', "
Gives me:
"ReflectionException in Route.php line 287: Class \App\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist"

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Ah, right. Try the same but with an extra \ at the very beginning. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Mark his answer as correct if it solved your problem

Comment: As I mentioned in my last ill formatted comment.
Adding "'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index', " Gives me: "ReflectionException in Route.php line 287: Class \App\Http\Controllers\HomeController does not exist"

Comment: We don't get notifications if you edit your comments. It's better to reply again. :) What's the namespace in your HomeController right now?

Comment: Oh! I had no idea on what basis you where notified of my updates! @joel I'll try and take that into account from now on! I'll edit my original question with my up`dates